# Find equation of the tangent plane to the surface $f = (x^2y + 2y^2z + 3z^2x = 6$ at point $(1,1,1)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tangent-line

So the tangent plane would be $$T(x_0) = f(x_0) + \nabla f(x-x_0) $$I think the notation here might not be correct for the tangent plane, but I think that I have the right idea (as you see later)

First I find the gradient vector, $\nabla f = (2xy + 3z^2, x^2 + 4yz, 2y^2 + 6zx)$. Then I find $\nabla f (1,1,1) = (5,5,8)$.

Then plugging into the tangent plane equation, I get $$ T(1,1,1) = 6 + (5,5,8) \cdot \begin{pmatrix} x-1 \\ y-1 \\ z-1\end{pmatrix}$$ which simplifies to $T(x_0) = 5x + 5y + 8z - 12$ or $12 = 5x + 5y + 8z$. Is something off with this? Or do the steps look all correct for the most part?

Comment: You can check your own work: The point $(1,1,1)$ doesn’t satisfy your plane equation, so something has clearly gone wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tangent plane is

$$ T(1,1,1) = 0 + (5,5,8) \cdot \begin{pmatrix} x-1 \\ y-1 \\ z-1\end{pmatrix}$$

which simplifies to $18 = 5x + 5y + 8z$

Comment: Where do you get the 0 from?

Comment: @Evan Kim - $ (x^2y + 2y^2z + 3z^2x -6=0$ at the point $(1,1,1)$.